# Is it possible to have an association with the same model, but some records have another association to go through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Kind of a difficult concept to put into a title, but here is the use case:

I have `users`, the `users` can either belong to a `partner` or a `customer`. A `partner` can have many `customer`s, but all `user`s have a `partner` either directly or indirectly. Is there any way to create an association that would allow for `partner` access on any `user` regardless of whether or not they are directly related to it?
This is my current setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :partner, through: :user_join, :source => :userable, :source_type => "Licensee"
  has_one :customer, through: :user_join, :source => :userable, :source_type => "Customer"
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
  has_many :user_joins, as: :userable
  has_many :users, through: :user_joins
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner
  has_many :user_joins, as: :userable
  has_many :users, through: :user_joins
end
```

Comment: I am confusing with this: `all users have a partner either directly or indirectly`, could you explain `directly and indirectly`? Which model user can have partner through?

Comment: A user can have a partner either directly (`user` -> `partner`) or indirectly (`user` -> `customer` -> `partner`).

Comment: This seems like a classic polymorphism use case, since partner and customer are subclasses of user.  It seems like each user could have one partner and many customers.